# JSON_MODIFY append $..... already exist instead update,duplicating value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to add or update using `JSON_MODIFY append $.roles` in json object `roles` properties.
But it's seem like instead of updating existing object adding new object.how to solve this not got solution yet.

here is query:

```
    SELECT json_modify(fs1.[Schema], 'append $.roles', json_query(
       (
              SELECT ar1.rolename AS [role],
                     ar1.[create] AS [permissions.create],
                     ar1.[read]   AS [permissions.read],
                     ar1.[update] AS [permissions.update],
                     ar1.[delete] AS [permissions.delete] FOR json path,
                     without_array_wrapper ))) AS [Schema]
FROM   applicationroles ar1
JOIN   commonformsschema fs1
ON     ar1.schemaid= fs1.schemaid
```

**`Schema` column input json:**

```
    {
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "Senior Project Manager",
      "permissions": {
        "create": true,
        "read": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
      }
    },
    {
      "role": "Read",
      "permissions": {
        "create": false,
        "read": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Current Result:**

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "Senior Project Manager",
      "permissions": {
        "create": true,
        "read": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
      }
    },
    {
      "role": "Read",
      "permissions": {
        "create": false,
        "read": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
      }
    },
    {
      "role": "Read",
      "permissions": {
        "create": false,
        "read": true,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected result:**

```
{
  "roles": [
    {
      "role": "Senior Project Manager",
      "permissions": {
        "create": true,
        "read": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
      }
    },
    {
      "role": "Read",
      "permissions": {
        "create": false,
        "read": true,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

how to solve this?
thanks.

Comment: How do you identify whether to add or update?

Comment: if rolename object exists means update else add

Comment: Then does the answer not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` is only used if you want to add another object to the array.

If you want to modify the existing object, use the array index:

```sql
SELECT json_modify(fs1.[Schema], '$.roles[1]', json_query(
       (
              SELECT ar1.rolename AS [role],
                     ar1.[create] AS [permissions.create],
                     ar1.[read]   AS [permissions.read],
                     ar1.[update] AS [permissions.update],
                     ar1.[delete] AS [permissions.delete]
              FOR json path, without_array_wrapper
       ))
     ) AS [Schema]
FROM   applicationroles ar1
JOIN   commonformsschema fs1
  ON   ar1.schemaid = fs1.schemaid;
```

If you don't know whether to add or update, and you are checking based on `rolename`, instead you can query the current value's index, and update that.

> This only works on SQL Server 2017

```sql
SELECT json_modify(fs1.[Schema],
      ISNULL(N'$.roles[' + j.[key] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 + N']', N'append $.roles'), json_query(
       (
              SELECT ar1.rolename AS [role],
                     ar1.[create] AS [permissions.create],
                     ar1.[read]   AS [permissions.read],
                     ar1.[update] AS [permissions.update],
                     ar1.[delete] AS [permissions.delete]
              FOR json path, without_array_wrapper
       ))
     ) AS [Schema]
FROM   applicationroles ar1
JOIN   commonformsschema fs1
  ON   ar1.schemaid = fs1.schemaid
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) j.[key]
    FROM OPENJSON(fs1.[Schema], '$.roles') j
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.value, '$.rolename') = ar1.rolename
) j;
```

Comment: getting error  like Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Comment: Sorry forgot `[key]` needs brackets

Comment: Cannot resolve collation conflict between "Latin1_General_BIN2" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in json_modify operator occurring in SELECT statement column 1.

Comment: That's a rather old collation, but given you a fix for that also. I think it's because that is your default server collation